# How to wrap a Java Web Start in .exe?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm afraid that many users still don't know what Java Web Start, so they may get confused by the small, single `.jnlp` file. So is it possible to wrap it as a very normal application, i.e. Windows `.exe`(or OSX `.app`) with pretty icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The [`shortcut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) element can be used to indicate an application's preferences for desktop integration." The `desktop` element in particular allows platform-specific integration in a way that users expect.

Answer (score 2):

I [wrote a script to fix-up the file association for executable .jar files](http://thegreenoak.blogspot.com/2012/11/dos-batch-script-to-assocation-jar.html).   You could just modify my script and that would give your users a way to register the .jnlp extension if it wasn't yet registered on their system.

NOTE: In the case where you have a user who hasn't installed Java on their system, they wouldn't have this file association, and you could use this script to associate a "bundled jre" with .jnlp extensions without the user needing to install Java.

Answer (score 1):

Basically JAVA runs on a virtual machine, but cross-compilers can be used to re-compile your java code , creating an .exe or .app file

Answer (score 1):

if javafx is an option, linked article describes nice ways how to deploy the same application both as .exe and .jnlp

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1324980

Comment: +1 for citing the current [*Installable Package Formats*](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1324980).